# Clearing Chrome's cache, cookies, etc via command line? (OSX)

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, browser-cache

Is it possible to clear chrome's browser cache, & cookies, etc via the command line? 
I'm on Mac OSX 10.9

I've written a script that switches from development and production environments & it would be really nice to add this to it.

Comment: Another option to consider in switching development environments is in the use of virtual machines. Using two virtual machines on your host machine you could have both a development and production environment running at the same time and they would not interfere with each other. Check out [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In OS X, your Chrome cache is located at:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/
```

To delete the cache you could type:

```
rm -rf /Users/[username]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache/
```

There is also a media cache in there that you can nuke:

```
rm -rf /Users/[username]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Media\ Cache/
```

Other Chrome data is located at:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
```

Comment: Anyone know the path to Chrome cache on Ubuntu?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson, that is worth asking a new question.

Comment: How to delete a specific site cache insead of clear all the cache from chrome?

Answer (score 3):

You can clear specific cookies from Chrome, by using sqlite and its command line interface.

Here's a post on Superuser on how to do this:
https://superuser.com/a/920604

Answer (score 2):

Try this

## Clear Chrome Cache

rm -R /Users/*/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache

Comment: He said he is on a Mac.